# Using multiprocessing 2.6.2.1 package in Jython

Tags: python, jython

I'm new to Jython/Python world. I'm trying to install the multiprocessing package in Jython. However I'm getting following return message from the easy_install

```
Setup script exited with error: Compiling extensions is not supported on Jython
```

Is there any way I can install this package in Jython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use it if `multiprocessing` requires C extensions i.e., if you can't disable them and the module was not reimplemented for Jython in Java/pure Python. `multiprocessing` module is included in the stdlib since Python 2.6. Current Jython supports Python 2.5.

There is no GIL in Jython so you can use `threading` in many cases where you would use `multiprocessing` in CPython.

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago I spoke with the author of multiprocessing (Jesse Noller) about the sensibility of including a version of multiprocessing in Jython. His response was similar to the one J.F. Sebastian posted - The multiprocessing module is intended to be a drop in replacement for the threading module as a way to get around CPython's GIL. Since Jython has no GIL, it makes no sense to support multiprocessing.

Comment: I disagree with *"it makes no sense to support multiprocessing"*. `multiprocessing` uses processes and therefore it provides a better isolation by default and it allows to communicate with processes on different hosts over the network.

Comment: It makes sense for compatibility with existing code.